# Reason for why $ 2f(A)f(B) =0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ f_{A\bigtriangleup B}=f_A +f_B-2f(A)f(B)$

Why $2f(A)f(B) =0$  if I have $f$ an function from power set $ R$ to a ring $ Z_2$

Comment: Then $f(A),f(B),2\in \mathbb{Z}/2$ with $2=0$, so $2f(A)f(B)=0f(A)f(B)=0$.

Comment: Your question is not clear; why write $f_A$ and $f(A)$, are they different values? By the way, this is not true for _any_ function $R\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$; you need some form of linearity hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the ring $Z_2$, $2x=0$ since $2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2x$ means $x + x$.  However, for $x \in \Bbb Z_2$, we have $2x = x + x = 0$ for any choice of $x$.  So, if $f:R \to \Bbb Z_2$, then $2f(A)f(B) = 0$.